# Convert Any to Array<Object>

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an variable `ranks` that out output below, however this is of type `Any`. However i want to convert it into `Array<Ladder>` so far i i've tried to write `as! [Ladder]`, but does not work.

```
Optional(Optional(Set([Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53474;
    name = Gold;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53478;
    name = Challenger;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53476;
    name = Diamond;
}])))
```

**Eureka function**

```
        <<< MultipleSelectorRow<Ladder>("Rank") {
            $0.hidden = Condition.predicate(NSPredicate(format: "$Game == nil"))
            $0.title = $0.tag


            }.cellUpdate { cell, row in

                let formvalues = self.form.values()
                let game = formvalues["Game"] as! Game
                let ranks = Array(game.ranks)
                row.options = ranks
                row.displayValueFor = { (rowValue: Set<Ladder>?) in
                    return rowValue?.map({ $0.name }).sorted().joined(separator: ", ")
                }


                cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 16)

                cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
                cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
                cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Array(ranks)` yet?

Comment: yes `Argument type Any?? does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'`

Comment: Okay, can you provide more information where that ranks variable comes from? And how it's created?

Comment: i'm using a table form repository called eureka, where when i get the form value i get it as a Any type. However what i basically want is to just map it so i get an array of the ids

Comment: What function Eureka does the variable come from?

Comment: @YannickWinter i've added the function now. where you can see in `options` and `displayValueFOr`

Comment: Okay so the `row.options` doesn't take your `ranks` or do you want to read the selected ranks? Please provide more information in your question.